# Inherit generic type in nested enum implementing interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, nested, abstract

I try to write a generic abstract class for my state machine, that will be utilizing enum implementing some interface defined inside that abstract class. I have an abstract class which contains a field implementing a generic interface and some wrapper functions for state switching logic. I try to extend this abstract class and create nested enum type implementing this generic interface, but there are some places, where I have to define explicitely which types I am using for generics. The code below demostrates this problem

```java
public abstract class FiniteStateMachine<C, I> { // <- generic types declared here
   private State<C, I> currentState;
   protected FiniteStateMachine(State<C, I> initial){ currentState = initial; }
   // some other methods for FSM, that I don't want to include in State<>
   // ...

   public synchronized void process(C context, I input) {
      State<C, I> nextState = currentState.process(context, input)
      if(currentState != nextState){
         currentState.onExit(nextState, context);
         State<C, I> previousState = currentState;
         currentState = nextState;
         nextState.onEnter(previousState, context);
      }
   }

   public interface State<C, I> { //<- this interface should use the same types as FiniteStateMachine
      State<C, I> process(C context, I input);
      default void onEnter(State<C, I> s, C context) {}
      default void onExit(State<C, I> s, C context) {}
   }
}
```

```java
class FSM extends FiniteStateMachine<Data, String> { // <- here I define types used for FSM
   public FSM() { super(FSMStage.START); }

   enum FSMState implements State<Data, String> { // <- and here I have to repeat them
      START{
         @Override
         public FSMState process(Data p, String s) {
            // ...
            return NEXT;
         },
         @Override
         public void onExit(State s, Data d) { /* ... */ }
      },
      NEXT{
         // ...
      }

   }
}
```

The main concern is that type information is defined in multiple places in extending class - once in type info of the abstract class and onec in interface the enum implements.

FiniteStateMachine is abstract and not an interface because I need some flags and initial state fields (and I can't make an "abstract field" otherwise than with protected constructor hack). FiniteStateMachine.State is an interface, because it's used in enums which cannot be extended. I also want to keep FiniteStateMachine and FiniteStateMachineState in one file, because separate fiels create lots of bloat content in project. Also inside extending FSM the `onExit` method has a type of State instead of FSMStage.

I tried something like `FiniteStateMachine<C, I, State<C, I>>` but errors said that 'State is not accessible in the context'.

Is there any way to declare the types in one place in extending class instead of FSM and FSMState like right now? Or maybe there is a way to declare types only for FSMState and make FSM reuse those types? Or maybe this design is completely flawed?

Comment: *"The main concern is that type information is defined in multiple places in extending class"* Why is that a concern? Are you just being lazy, not wanting to specify the types more than once? It's not like the types can be out of sync without causing compilation errors, so that's not really a concern.

Comment: @Andreas it looks superfluous. I presented this simple example, but what happens in a case of more complex classes and types? A lot of boilerplate code might potentially be introduced. If there is some method to inherit the generic types from other class, then it can be usefull in other scenarios, so I'd like to know if there is such possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that inner interfaces (and enums too btw) are implicitely static, so they cannot use generic parameters of outer class, because they have no access to instances of the outer class.

So basically this interface is inside the abstract class only for code convenience, you may aswell extract it to separate file. In this design I don't think there is a way to skip multiple generic type declarations.

I think changing the design just to avoid the re-declaration is not worth it - you could make `State` an abstract class and remove generic types from declaration so it gets generic types from the outer class, but then the idea with enums doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`C` in `FiniteStateMachine` is not the same `C` in `State` class, If you want to make them dependent, you have to define a third type in your `FiniteStateMachine` which uses `C` and `I` with `State`. You were almost right with `FiniteStateMachine<C, I, State<C, I>>`, but here how you can do it :

```java
public abstract class FiniteStateMachine<C, I, T extends FiniteStateMachine.State<C, I>> {
    private T currentState;
    protected FiniteStateMachine(T initial){ currentState = initial; }

    public synchronized void process(C context, I input) {
        FiniteStateMachine.State<C, I> nextState = currentState.process(context, input);
        if(currentState != nextState){
            currentState.onExit(nextState, context);
            State<C, I> previousState = currentState;
            currentState = (T) nextState;
            nextState.onEnter(previousState, context);
        }
    }

    public interface State<CTX, INPT> {
        State<CTX, INPT> process(CTX context, INPT input);
        default void onEnter(State<CTX, INPT> s, CTX context) {}
        default void onExit(State<CTX, INPT> s, CTX context) {}
    }
}
```

Now you force the types of `State` to be same as those defined in `FiniteStateMachine`.

You can use it now like :

```java
public class FSM extends FiniteStateMachine<Date, String, FSM.FSMState> { 
    public FSM() { super(FSMState.START); }

    public enum FSMState implements FiniteStateMachine.State<Date, String> {
        START{
            @Override
            public FSMState process(Date p, String s) {
                // ...
                return NEXT;
            }

            @Override
            public void onExit(FiniteStateMachine.State s, Date d) { /* ... */ }
        },
        NEXT{
            @Override
            public FiniteStateMachine.State<Date, String> process(Date context, String input) {
                return null;
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, what about repeating the generic types !? From what i've learned so far, there's no way to simplify the writing of your classes. I think the origin of your question was when the two classes are declared in the same file. What if they were separated in two different files ? Do you continue thinking this way ?

Comment: It would be a solution if FSMState was in a separate file, otherwise a "State is not accessible in current context" arises when trying to add the `FSM.FSMState` to the generic types of FSM. Separating FSMState to other file works, but there is now a problem of one state machine requiring 2 files. It may look like it's something minor, but in big projects containing tens of FSMs, the number of files to manage grows and grows. I think I'l stay with my initial solution and just repeat the types in `implements` clause. It's kinda sad, that Java doesn't have any mechanism for inheriting generics.

Comment: After looking further into this, it seems like just one extra parameter is added to the `FiniteStateMachine` definition, but the effect is the same as in my initial case. `State` interface in your case is enforced by generic definition of `FiniteStateMachine` whereas in mine it's enforced by the type of `currentState` field with interface's generics bound to `FiniteStateMachine` generics. That's even more boilerplate, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Tooster ah you want to enforce the types by the `currentState` field ? i don't know this technic ! what if your field is no longer here ? you wanna change all your design ?

Comment: In this design I create "abstract fields" in abstract class by defining my fields final and initializing them in non-default constructor, so each class extending it will always have them. The point was to enforce that generics of `currentState` be the same as generics in enclosing class - if my `FSM` uses `FSMState`, which on the other hand accepts `Context` and `Input` types, then there should be no need to explicitely define those variables again for the `FSM`, because it could be then inherited from `FSMState`. Or the other way around - `FSMState` generics be inherited from `FSM` class.